# Specifically, what does the Google Finance average volume indicate?

Tags: stocks

From my understanding, the average volume measurement on a stock in Google Finance is over a period of 3 months. Is this the average daily volume over 3 months, or is this the average monthly volume over 3 months?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I hovered over the label for trading volume and the following message popped up:

> Volume / average volume
>
> Volume is the number of shares traded on the
>   latest trading day. The average volume is measured over 30 days.